# I want to learn to program a simple game... where do I start?

Tags: jquery, html, 2d-games

I'm proficient in HTML/CSS and Javascript, and I've seen some pretty great yet simple games built with HTML5 and jQuery (I assume), but I cannot figure out where to get started.  I get there are many different engines, but what even is an engine.  Do I need one, or do I just need to learn to use HTML and jQuery creatively?  Either way, where is a good source for beginner level tutorials?

Thank you!

Comment: There was a great challenge a while back called 10K Apart. There are some great examples of some little games created efficiently, yet beautifully: http://10k.aneventapart.com/ It's all script and markup so obviously, you can get at the source code for the entries too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will have to agree with Max00355, just start.

http://gamedev.tutsplus.com/ is a good resource imho.

Answer (score 1):

You start by just doing it. It is overwhelming choosing the right engine that you should use, that's why you test a few out and see which ones that you like, and stick with it. It is like choosing a web framework in a language like Python. There are hundreds of different choices, but most likely you will only choose one, and with that one you can do anything anyone else can do with a different framework.

A game engine is just some code that makes it easier to write games. It takes out all the hard stuff like writing the code to render images, or writing the code to move images, and lets you jump right in to creating the game.

Good luck! And remember, the best way to learn is to dive in.

Comment: oh I'm absolutely ready to just jump in, but [the list of options](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines) is daunting.  I was hoping someone had already just jumped in and could point to a place where, if they had it to do over again, they would jump in at

Comment: The thing is, there is no answer to that question because everyone is different. What I did when I tried to learn game development is I first crated the design on paper and tried to recreate everything I had on paper in code. It doesn't matter how I did it as long as I did it.